# How to define the scope of search of "Go to definition" for C/C++ in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope, definition

In VS Code, I have a workspace with two folders (two C/C++ projects): P1 and P2

I have two functions foo() defined in both projects (same prototype):

- P1/foo.c
- P2/foo.c

When I Ctrl+Click on a call to foo() in project P1, I expect to go to the definition of foo() in P1.

But VS Code suggests me and let me choose between both definitions of foo() in either P1 and P2.

How to limit VS Code to look for definition in the parent folder only and not in the whole workspace ?

I tried to play with the compile_command and browse.path without success.

Comment: not sure, but have you tried using a multi-root workspace instead? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Comment: Yes I use multi root folder.